# Watir and Javascript button

Tags: javascript, button, watir

How can I click a button in Watir that is defined like this:

```
<div id="divAddCompany" onclick="AddComp()">
<span>Add company</span>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript code looks like this:

```
    function AddComp() {
    HideComp();
    $(hide).css({ visibility: "visible", height: "auto" });
    var a = document.getElementById("divSave");
    a.onclick = InsertCompany;
}
```

I tried in Watir :

```
browser.text_field(:id, "Add company").click
browser.button(:name, "Add company").fire_event
browser.div(:name, /divAddCompany/).button(:value, "Add company").click
```

Any other suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with :

```
browser.div(:id, "divAddCompany").click
```